# Error in Jquery function "output html is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code to print out the list of users, when I try to run it I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: ".output".html is not a function,

what am I doing wrong here? any help or suggestions will be helpful.

NOTE: I tested using console.log, I get the results what I want.

HTML Code:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="output">Show output</div>
</body>
</htm>
```

Jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
      $.getJSON("http://zadanie.laboratorium.ee/users.json",function(data)
     {
         var items = [];
         var number_of_user = 0;
         var number_of_active_user = 0;
         var number_of_active_men = 0;
         var number_of_active_women = 0;
            $.each(data,
             function(key, value)
             {
              number_of_user += 1;
              if(value['active'] == true){
                 if(value['gender'][0] == 'Female' || value['gender'][0] == 'female'){
                    number_of_active_women +=1;
                 }
                 else if(value['gender'][0] == 'Male' || value['gender'][0] == 'male'){
                    number_of_active_men +=1;
                 }
              }

             });


             (".output").html("number_of_user ==> "+number_of_user +" number_of_active_user ==> "+ number_of_active_user +" number_of_active_men ==> "+ number_of_active_men +" number_of_active_women ==> "+ number_of_active_women);

     });
   });
```

Comment: use:
$(".output")

Comment: I've voted to close this because it is caused by a simple typo (missing `$`).

Comment: damn thanks , I am tired lol :( wtf

Answer (score 0):

You're missing your `$` at the start of `('.output')`.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
      $.getJSON("http://zadanie.laboratorium.ee/users.json",function(data)
     {
         var items = [];
         var number_of_user = 0;
         var number_of_active_user = 0;
         var number_of_active_men = 0;
         var number_of_active_women = 0;
            $.each(data,
             function(key, value)
             {
              number_of_user += 1;
              if(value['active'] == true){
                 if(value['gender'][0] == 'Female' || value['gender'][0] == 'female'){
                    number_of_active_women +=1;
                 }
                 else if(value['gender'][0] == 'Male' || value['gender'][0] == 'male'){
                    number_of_active_men +=1;
                 }
              }

             });

            // ADDED THE JQUERY $ HERE
             $(".output").html("number_of_user ==> "+number_of_user +" number_of_active_user ==> "+ number_of_active_user +" number_of_active_men ==> "+ number_of_active_men +" number_of_active_women ==> "+ number_of_active_women);

     });
   });
```